# Unit tests fail on MacBook with AppleSilicon M1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, apple-silicon

I had a quite old (3-4 years old) project of the iOS application. It worked fine on my Macbook Air M1 - builds, tests, worked fine. One day I realized that my unit tests are broken, I tried to fix them, but as a result I got a completely not working project. Probably refactoring with renaming broke it one day. And I was not able to recover it (finding the cause by reverting tons of commits was not an option). So long story short: I ended up with creating new project and copying all the resources there. And reworking and updating Podfile.

So I created a project, copied source files there and now I am build the app, run it in simulator and even build for testing. But I am not able to run tests:

- If I choose target device iPhone - I'm getting error `mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')` in output:

```
2023-07-26 22:12:11.314305+0200 xctest[97922:9567290] [loading] Error loading /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests (182):  
dlopen(/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests, 0x0109): 
tried: '/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib/iCafeManagerProTests' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests' (no such file), 
'/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
2023-07-26 22:12:11.316272+0200 xctest[97922:9567290] The bundle “iCafeManagerProTests” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture. Try installing a universal version of the bundle.
2023-07-26 22:12:11.316332+0200 xctest[97922:9567290] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests) => false, tried: '/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib/iCafeManagerProTests' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests' (no such file), 
'/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')))
Program ended with exit code: 80
```

- If I choose target device iPhone (Rosetta) - I'm getting error `Library not loaded: @rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth` in the output:

```
2023-07-26 22:23:10.355802+0200 xctest[99474:9579988] The bundle “iCafeManagerProTests” couldn’t be loaded. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2023-07-26 22:23:10.355957+0200 xctest[99474:9579988] (dlopen(/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests, 0x0109): Library not loaded: @rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth
  Referenced from: <9F352880-C322-379E-86F1-A65ADFFEB514> /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/iCafeManagerProTests
  Reason: tried: '/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iCafeManagerPro-exbawzxzvvmwrqcjuijflsigwiuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iCafeManagerProTests.xctest/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file), 
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' (no such file))
```

I have:

- MacOS Ventura
- XCode Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)
- Macbook M1 2020

Podfile:

```rb
platform :ios, '12.3'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!
# use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

target 'iCafeManagerPro' do
  pod "SearchTextField", '~> 1.2.4'
  pod 'DGCharts', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'Firebase', '~> 10.12.0'
  pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 13.0.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 14.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 14.1.0'
  pod 'FirebaseFacebookAuthUI', '~> 13.0.0'

  target 'iCafeManagerProTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Tests target build settings - Architecture:
[image]

I tried to play with these settings for Test target. Tried to remove arm64 exclusion for it - it causes build failure:

```
/Users/dj-glock/repos/iCafeManagerPro/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/gpr/string.h
/Users/dj-glock/repos/iCafeManagerPro/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/gpr/string.h:27:10 'string' file not found
/Users/dj-glock/repos/iCafeManagerPro/iCafeManagerProTests/Generic/Extensions/Foundation/String/StringExtensionToFloatTests.swift
/Users/dj-glock/repos/iCafeManagerPro/iCafeManagerProTests/Generic/Extensions/Foundation/String/StringExtensionToFloatTests.swift Could not build Objective-C module 'Darwin'
```

I checked many SO questions and other articles - nothing helped so far. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered cleaning?

Clean the build folder by pressing Shift + Command + K.
Delete the DerivedData folder. You can find its location in Xcode > Preferences > Locations.

Comment: @Joaquin yes, I tried to clean, no luck.